# Problem with user uploading images in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to use the `Django` framework to design a user personal picture uploading system. The completed content includes a Django project name named SGV. The project inclue a name call Success app to handle various requests from users. After the user logs in, It will jump to a webpage named userhome.html. I want to upload pictures of the current webpage in this userhome without jumping to other pages. After the pictures are uploaded, they will be saved to the user_file/image folder in the root directory of the project. , the problem is that after I finished writing part of the code, I found that I could select the file, but nothing happened after clicking the upload image button, not even any error. Is there any kind person who can help me, a newbie in Django?

The following is some code within the project, which may not be fully displayed. If you want to know more, please tell me.

**Userhome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <title>SGV UserHome</title>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/system.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <h1>Welcome to User Home</h1>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="image-input">
            <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload Image</button>
        </form>
        <div id="image-preview"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('upload-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(this);
            fetch('/upload/', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    // Display a success message or update the page as needed
                    document.getElementById('image-preview').innerHTML = '<p>Image uploaded successfully!</p>';
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where the upload was not successful
                    document.getElementById('image-preview').innerHTML = '<p>Upload failed. Please try again.</p>';
                }
            });
        });

        // Preview the selected image
        document.getElementById('image-input').addEventListener('change', function () {
            const imagePreview = document.getElementById('image-preview');
            imagePreview.innerHTML = '';
            const file = this.files[0];
            if (file) {
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                img.style.maxWidth = '100%';
                imagePreview.appendChild(img);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views.py Upload_file**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        try:
            # Use pillow to verify whether it is a picture
            image = Image.open(uploaded_file)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'The uploaded file is not of image type!'})

        with open('./user_file/media' + uploaded_file.name, 'wb') as destination:
            for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Image upload success!'})

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Image upload error!'})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path ,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name="index"),
    path('signup',views.signup,name="signup"),
    path('signin',views.signin,name="signin"),
    path('signout',views.signout,name="signout"),
    path('userhome',views.test,name="userhome"),
    path('upload/', views.upload_file, name='upload_file'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='./user_files/media')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'success'
```

Comment: please specify your error.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying that there are few things wrong, both in `models` and `views` in terms of design and best practice. Although, first things first, to make your current code work, adjust the field you are trying to retrieve from `request.FILES`, its called `image` not `file`. And, provide [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) a valid path. **(Note: The way it is, you have to manually create the folders inside your project.)**

```py
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['image']:
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['image']
        try:
            # Use pillow to verify whether it is a picture
            image = Image.open(uploaded_file)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'The uploaded file is not of image type!'})

        with open('user_file/media/' + uploaded_file.name, 'wb') as destination:
            for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Image upload success!'})

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Image upload error!'})
```

### Another way

So, what is wrong? You have a potent tool in your hand and you are not using it properly. By not creating relations, not using your model and doing a shallow validation.

The most important thing is that with the current structure you can never know which image belongs to which user, its all mixed. Thus, it is necessary to [relate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/) them:

```py
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=uploaded_image_path)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="pictures"
    )
```

This way, it is also possible to [separate the files per user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), inside your storage:

```py
def uploaded_image_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{}/media/{}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

With a model you can create a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) to easily validate your data. In this case, the form will create a [`forms.ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield) that will ensure the file-upload field data contains a valid image (Form which you could use to render your template instead of writing it yourself).

```
class UploadedImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedImage
        fields = ["image"]
```

Then, we use all of that inside the view. Note the addition of `success` key to the response corresponding to your frontend handler, where I also recommend that you use async/await and arrow functions.

```py
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadedImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()

            return JsonResponse({
                "message": "Image upload success!", 
                "success": True
            })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
                "message": "The uploaded file is not of image type!", 
                "success": False
            })
```

Finally, you can access an `User` image set (`pictures`, because that is how the [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is set):

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1) 
>>> user.pictures.all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient answer. You are my code hero today. However, I spent a whole night troubleshooting last night and still couldn't solve the problem. It even almost crashed the webpage I originally wrote.

Comment: As I stated, your original code will work with a few adjustments that are written in the first code block of my answer. Otherwise feel free to ask.

Comment: After two days of troubleshooting, I solved it. Thank you. In addition, I would also like to know if there is a way to display the user folder in the html web page?

Comment: If you implemented with relations, just use `user.pictures.all()` that will fetch every image  inside the folder for a given user instance. Then, just loop through it.  `{%for obj in user.pictures.all %} <a href={{obj.image.url}}>{{obj.image}}</a> {%endfor%}` (ofc you will need a new template.)